# RPL routing neighbors

Tags: routes, iot, contiki

Just to be on the safe side, please CORRECT me if I am wrong.
When RPL is in storing mode, each node knows its direct children and via which child a given node can be accessed. 
E.g., the following topology

```
7-6-5-1-2-3-4 
  | |     |
  8 10    9
```

If the node No 1 wants to send a msg to node 7, it will send it to 5 without knowing where exactly No 7 is. Node No 5 will send it to No 6 who knows that it is "directly" connected to 7.
On the other hand, if No 1 wants to send a msg to No 4, it will send it to No 2, who knows that No 4 is accessible via No 3.

Answer (score 0):

In RPL, downward routes are learned through unicast DAO messages. Each nodes appends itself  in the DAO messages when child nodes sends DAO to root node. Thus each nodes has complete knowledge of routes to child nodes. However, the communication is done in hop-by-hop fashion. Where nodes sends data to its next hop neighbor.

Thus, node 1 has complete route to 7 as well as 4.

Comment: What you describe is correct only for non storing mode. In storing mode, every node receiving a DAO replaces the IP of the sender with its own IP and forwards to the parent. When the DAO reaches the sink, it has two IPs: The originating sender, and the child of the sink. Hence the sink knows only which way it has to send a msg for a particular node. As an example, in the topology above, if the sink (no 1) wants to send a msg to 8, it will forward it to 5. If it wants to send a msg to 9, it will forward it to 2.